# Static instance does not work like I expect

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine

I'm doing some tests for the states of a game built using Unity, using something like the following:

*script 1*

```
public class ControladorEstados : MonoBehaviour {
    private static ControladorEstados controladorEstados = null;
    //public bool pause { get; set;} = false; //¿ usa c# 4? 
    private bool pause; 
    public bool Pause { 
        get { return pause;  } 
        set { pause = value; }
    }

    private bool gameOver;
    public bool GameOver {
        get { return gameOver;  }
        set { gameOver = value; }
    }

    //protected ControladorEstados () {}    
    private ControladorEstados () {}

    void Start () {
        pause = false;
        gameOver = false;
    }

    void Update () {
        Debug.Log("Update");

        if (gameOver == true) {
            Debug.Log("GameOver Game");
        }

        if (pause) {
            Debug.Log("Pause Game");
        }
    }

    public static ControladorEstados getInstancia () {
        if (controladorEstados == null) {
            controladorEstados = new ControladorEstados ();
        }
        return controladorEstados;
    }
}
```

---

*script 2*

```
    ..//

    private ControladorEstados controladorEstados = null;

    void Awake() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        controladorEstados = ControladorEstados.getInstancia ();
    }

    void Start() {
    }


    void Update () {
        // test
        gameOver ();
    }

    private void gameOver (){
        controladorEstados.GameOver = true;
        Debug.Log("test gameOver () " + controladorEstados.GameOver);
    }   
}
```

In the`test gameOver ()` log I can see that the variable is set to `true`, but the script `ControladorEstados` does not work as I expect when doing the update. It does not work as expected.

I have put `Debug.Log("Update");` To see if it was running the `Update`, and it is running, but it does not branch into the `if` statement when it is `true`.

I have no experience in C # or Unity, even though it seems embarrassing for me to ask this question, but I have been at this for a while and I do not see the error.  Additionally, I am using a Linux version and I do not know if that could be part of the error.

**Update:**

I just added this code change:

```
void Update () {
        Debug.Log("Update" + gameOver);

        if (gameOver == true) {
            Debug.Log("GameOver Game");
        }
..//
```

Its output is `False` so I can see it is not changing. In the *script 2* it is true, but in the *script 1* it is false.  Please give me some ideas as to what I am doing wrong.

**I solve it**

*script 1*

```
void Awake () {

    //controladorEstados = new ControladorEstados ();       

    if (controladorEstados == null) {
        controladorEstados = this;
    }
}

..//

public static ControladorEstados getInstancia () {
    return controladorEstados;
}
```

With the response of Peter Duniho I create the code above, You can see the changes and I also knew the use of **Script Execution Order** To use an order among them.

I do not know if it's the best way, but it seems to work, I post it in case someone helps with something similar.

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. What exactly is the issue? Who is calling `update` in script 1? who is calling it in script 2?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Update Is called by unity engine, is called once per frame, in each script. The question basically I think I can say, why in script 1 is false and script 2 is true?. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without [a good, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say for sure what you need to change to fix the problem.

But, it's clear you are dealing with two different instances of `ControladorEstados`. The instance that is running (and so the one for which Unity3d is calling the `ControladorEstados.Update()` method) is *not* the same instance that is being referenced by the `controladorEstados` variable in whatever class you are describing as *"script 2"*.

In your `ControladorEstados.getInstancia()` method, you should not be creating a new instance of `ControladorEstados`. Instead, you need to do two things:

1. Set `ControladorEstados.controladorEstados` in the `ControladorEstados` class when it's created, e.g. in the `Start()` method.
2. Make sure the class you describe as *"script 2"* does not call `getInstancia()` until after step #1 has occurred.

Note that the above is just the most minimal steps you can take to resolve the issue. In all likelihood, there is a better way to query the Unity3d API to allow *"script 2"* to retrieve *the* instance of `ControladorEstados` that you want (e.g. to return the current, correct controller instance from a scene, or something like that). But without a more complete code example, it's impossible to say for sure what that better approach would look like, exactly.

Comment: I found a solution left above, I do not know if it is the best way, but it seems to work, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not exactly the Unity way. You're basically mixing a singleton with a MonoBehaviour.

Remember that Unity is component-driven. If you want a single instance of an object that extends MonoBehaviour just create an object that's always in the scene (like a GameManager) and add `ControladorEstados` to it.

You can then reference it from there in scripts where you need to use it instead of using a singleton.